# Allowing user input with same name variables

Tags: java

I'm currently using the charAt(0) method to allow users to make an input. This is an issue because I have a variable that starts with the same char. I want the program to read the first 3 chars in this instance. In other words, how can I ensure my program recognizes the correct variable when chosen?

P.S- I know I need to work on naming conventions, I'm still new to Java and am learning.

```
switch(SkillChoice.nextLine().toLowerCase().charAt(0)){
        case 'd':
            System.out.println("How many points towards Dexterity?");
            System.out.println("Your current Dexterity is " + Attribute.Dexterity);

            SkillChoice.nextDouble();

            Attribute.setDex(SkillChoice.nextDouble() + Attribute.getDex());
            System.out.println(Attribute.Dexterity);
        case 's':
            System.out.println("How many points towards Strength?");
            System.out.println("Your current Strength is " + Attribute.Strength);

        SkillChoice.nextDouble();

            Attribute.setStr(SkillChoice.nextDouble() + Attribute.getStr());
            System.out.println(Attribute.Strength);
        case 's':
            System.out.println("How many points towards Strength?");
            System.out.println("Your current Strength is " + Attribute.Stamina);

             SkillChoice.nextDouble();

            Attribute.setSta(SkillChoice.nextDouble() + Attribute.getSta());
            System.out.println(Attribute.Dexterity);
        case 'i':
            System.out.println("How many points towards Intelligence?");
            System.out.println("Your current Intelligence is " + Attribute.Intelligence);

            SkillChoice.nextDouble();

            Attribute.setInt(SkillChoice.nextDouble() + Attribute.getInt());
            System.out.println(Attribute.Intelligence);
```

When prompted, the user should be able to type "Str****" or "Sta****" where * is any string combination, and the program should recognize it as wanting to increase strength or stamina points.

Comment: The initial case 's' should be for strength, and the secondary case 's' should be for stamina.

Comment: You might want to save the characters in a String which you build up with every new character and use `startWith()` to see if you have any matches. If you have more than one match you need more characters. If you have exactly one match you know which attribute to select. If you have no matches at all, then you have entered something which is not recognizable.

Comment: Another thing is that each `case` *does not* end with `break`, that means that the code execution will 'fall-through' to the next case. That is serious trouble. For example, if `'d'` is selected, then all statements within the whole `switch` block will be executed because of the absence of `break`s.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get rid of the whole *switch/case* code and stick to *if*-clauses. That is because with the things I explain below it won't work with *switch/case*, if you really want to stick with it you should at least look up the right syntax because you are missing any *breaks*

That way you could simply use the method *startsWith* of the *String* class ( Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String- )

In your case the usage should look a little like this:

```
if(SkillChoice.nextLine().toLowerCase().startsWith("str") {
    System.out.println("How many points towards Strength?");
    System.out.println("Your current Strength is " + Attribute.Strength);

    SkillChoice.nextDouble();

    Attribute.setStr(SkillChoice.nextDouble() + Attribute.getStr());
    System.out.println(Attribute.Strength);
}
else if(SkillChoice.nextLine().toLowerCase().startsWith("sta") {
// Your stamina stuff here
}
```

Good luck & greetings from Germany

PS: I hope (especially) *Attribute* is not really a classname (the capital A would indicate it), because that would mean that all your methods in that class are static because otherwhys you would need an object of the class to call them. Either way, it's bad and you should concentrate on getting rid of these mistakes because they really make code unreadable for you and others as your project grows bigger.